# Java socket client: waiting for the response patiently

Tags: java, sockets

I have created a server via sockets with the help of [quickserver.org](http://www.quickserver.org/). The server runs solidly.

Now I had to write the client that sends a request (just a string value) to the server for an instruction and waits for its response (xml as string). This works fine when the triggered process by the request on server is not very time consuming. Unfortunately the client connection breaks as far as the server needs a long time for the process and that leads for a connection break and the client doesn't get anything back.

Here is the client code:

```
public String sendAndReceive(String message) throws IOException {
    PrintWriter printWriter = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(this.socket.getOutputStream()));
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(this.socket.getInputStream()));
    printWriter.print(message);
    printWriter.flush();
    this.socket.shutdownOutput();
    String line = null;
    StringBuilder xmlResponse = new StringBuilder();
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
    {
        xmlResponse.append(line);
    }
    printWriter.close();
    reader.close();
    this.socket.close();
    return xmlResponse.toString();
  }
```

This method sends the request and waits for the response afterwards. I am not sure about the while loop but all examples I have found on web are praising this construction. On my point of view reader.readline() can be null because the server needs more time for the response and therefore the method ends without getting the response.

How is the best practice for socket clients waiting for the response patiently? What I am doing wrong?

Kind regards,
Hilderich

Answer (score 0):

You are probably getting timeout.
You can use Socket.setSoTimeout(int timeout) to change timeout (in milliseconds).

Comment: Thank you, from client side I did this already: 

this.socket = new Socket();
    this.socket.connect(new InetSocketAddress(host, port), (int)TimeUnit.MINUTES.toMillis(40));